# Byte array to Image C#

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I have a simple byte string (elements of a matrix read row by row) . I wish to plot it in a image in c#. Is there any simple way to do this.

On the internet I found byte array to image conversion , but I assume that for this the byte string should have a certain format because I did not see any establishing of the width and height.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll want to look at the `Graphics` class to build a context attached to a `Bitmap` or `Image` and then plot your values using `SetPixel`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please show us the “byte string” and “certain format” you’re talking about, and an example of the “image conversion”.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bytes string contains color data for each pixel of an image in a one of the supported [pixel formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx), you can create a `Bitmap` with a specific size using this constructor: [`Bitmap(int width, int height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx).

Then lock the bitmap into system memory using [`Bitmap.LockBits(Rectangle, ImageLockMode, PixelFormat)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) and get the address of the first pixel data in the bitmap using [`BitmapData.Scan0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0.aspx).

After that, you can manipulate the raw bitmap data. For example, you can copy your bytes into it using, for example, [`Marshal.Copy(Byte[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625.aspx).

And finally unlock the bitmap with [`Bitmap.UnlockBits(BitmapData)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits.aspx).

Voila! You have created a bitmap from a byte array.

Comment: It doesn't sound like he has color data, but raw data (eg output from a sensor of some kind).  Most of your answer is on target, but I doubt he will need `Marshal.Copy`.  More likely, he'll need to set bits individually.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this code:

```
public Bitmap ConvertBytesToImage(byte[] BytesToConvert)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(BytesToConvert);
    try { return new Bitmap(ms); }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Comment: -1: the OP says that he has the values in a matrix, not bytes that are already in an image format.